# Is it possible to create a trigger with FluentMigrator?

Tags: .net, fluent-migrator

Is it possible to create a trigger with FluentMigrator, without resorting to raw SQL?

I have looked through the object model for the version currently released on Nuget (FluentMigrator.1.0.1.0) and can't see a way of doing it.

Comment: Did you found a solution for that problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure you've figured out by now that the answer is no. And I don't think that triggers will be supported anytime soon. They are very database-specific and would require lots of code to cover all the different cases. See this article on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger

If you really want a Create.Trigger expression in FluentMigrator then pull requests are always welcome!

Answer (score 8):

You can use Execute.Script

```
[Migration(1)]
public class Migration_0001_Baseline : Migration
{

    public override void Up()
    {                        
        Execute.Script("script1.sql");        
    }

    public override void Down()
    {

    }        
}
```

Comment: It's in a file, but it's still "raw SQL."

Comment: You'll want a `Down` script too for Rollback / MigrateDown.